# Is it possible to add an attribute as an element?

Tags: xml

So I have some legacy code that generates XML. The problem is that it operates by opening and closing tags, and writes everything to file as it goes.

```
startTag("race")
endTag()
```

Would produce:

```
<race>
</race>
```

Which is all fine and well. Except some pieces of relevant information about the race can only be deduced at the time of the the endTag(). Namely endTime. The XML I want to produce would be:

```
<race startTime="123" endTime="456>
</race>
```

But I know that isn't possible without a significant rewrite. Which I'm not thrilled to do. What would be really great is if there was something equivalent to using xsl:attribute in an XSLT transform. Where I could end up with some XML like this:

```
<race startTime="123">
    <attribute name="endTime">
        456
    </attribute>
</race>
```

Where this was considered properly formatted.

Is this possible? Note that I'm not able to hack my way around the attribute requirement, since this has to conform to a schema I don't control. So I'll need a way to make this a "proper" attribute.

Comment: No, there's nothing like that. Where would it be located? Even if there was such a thing, you'd still have to modify the legacy code to _use_ it. What does the code do currently about endtime?

Comment: Nothing at all? I would only have to modify the part of the code making calls to the opening and closing of tags. Not the actual functions. It currently leaves them off, which prevents proper operation.

Comment: It currently leaves _what_ off? What, exactly, does it produce now, and what, exactly, do you need it to produce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the element in question is empty, then it shouldn't be too difficult. If your code is Java you could easily convert it to use XMLStreamWriter which allows a sequence calls like

```
startElement()
attribute()
attribute()
endElement()
```

and it handles this by delaying outputting the ">" at the end of the start tag until it knows all the attributes have arrived. But if you want to write the content "out of sequence", so the element content is output before the attributes, then you need a very different approach. For example, you could output your "attribute" as a processing instruction, and then do a post-process using XSLT to convert the processing instruction to an attribute on the containing element.

Comment: The XML writer I'm using is all custom code, and can't be avoided. You've seen right to the core of the issue, that I need to build it "out of sequence". I think your processing instruction suggestion is my best bet for now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The usual solution would indeed be to rewrite your code. You haven't given us anywhere near enough information to advise you on how easy or difficult that would be. The usual solution is either to pass the attributes to the method which writes out the start-tag, or to delay actually writing out the start-tag syntax until all you know that no more attributes will be added (which is how a typical XSLT serializer works, so it can handle the `<xsl:attribute>` instruction).

Or you could build the entire document in memory, so you can easily go back and re-edit previously constructed parts of the tree.

Or you could solve this in other ways. Which one would make most sense depends on all those things you didn't tell us about what your code is trying to do, what XML library it's using, etc.